# How do I write an html file that runs JavaScript when an android app opens it?

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

How do I write an html file so that when a specific android app runs the html file it will run JavaScript? The android app has a function within it called `examplefunction()`

The html I expect would look something similar to this, however I cannot get it right.

```java
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.write(javascript:Android.examplefunction())
</script>"
</body>
</html>
```

the android app runs

```java
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
webView.loadUrl("www.example.com/test.html");
```

I am reading html like this

```java
public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String str) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.document.body.outerHTML})();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                public void onReceiveValue(String str) {
                   (code that uses the output of examplefunction())
        }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Communication between javascript and android and passing a value from javascript to Android can be referred [here](https://android.i-visionblog.com/android-webview-75fddf4d6a97)

You can use the following script in html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
     function showAndroidToast()  {
         android.showToast(Date());
     }
     showAndroidToast();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Place a showToast method in your java code and refer the javascript interface with name "android" in your java code.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and a several variants, but when it is opened and the html is read it replies with `<script>function showAndroidToast(){\nAndroid.examplefunction()\n}\nshowAndroidToast(); </script>` rather than `<script> (output of example function) </script>`